# How can I run a Dispatcher.Invoke() in a .NET Core 3 class library?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, .net-core-3.1

I am developing a WPF/NetCore3.1 application with MVVM. In the view there is a button which is bound to a RelayCommand.  The ViewModel is in a different class library than the View. In the ViewModel a timer is started which increments a variable every second and triggers the CanExecuteChanged event of the RelayCommand.

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public ImportExportViewModel()
{
    MakeOfferCommand = new RelayCommand(MakeOffer, CanMakeOffer);


    Timer t = new Timer(1000);
    t.Elapsed += T_Elapsed;
    t.Start();
}

private void T_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{            
    ElapsedTime++;

    MakeOfferCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}

private void MakeOffer()
{
    // TODO Make Offer
}

private bool CanMakeOffer()
{
    return ElapsedTime < 60;
}
```

And here the RaiseCanExecuteChanged:

```
public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
    var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

But here I get an InvalidOperationException: the calling thread cannot access this object because the object is owned by another thread.

Normally I would execute a Dispatcher.Invoke() here, but that seems not to exist in .NetCore3.1.

Can anyone tell me how I can still make cross-thread calls?

Comment: Use a DispatcherTimer in the first place. Besides that you don't need it, the Dispatcher is of course available in .NET Core 3. Probably you just didn't use the correct Project Sdk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The dispatcher timer works. But I have to change the SDK from my core project to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop and set UseWpf to true, which makes the class library not cross-platform anymore. Is there another way? Or should I start the timer in the View and call a corresponding method in the ViewModel from there?

Comment: That would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could inject your view model with an `IDispatch` interface that you implement in each platform:

**Interface:**

```
public interface IDispatch
{
    bool CheckAccess();
    void Invoke(Action action);
}
```

**View Model:**

```
public IDispatch Dispatch { get; set; }

private void T_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Dispatch != null && !Dispatch.CheckAccess())
        Dispatch.Invoke(new Action(() => { /* do something */ }));
    ...
}
```

**WPF implementation:**

```
public class WpfDispatch : IDispatch
{
    private readonly Dispatcher _dispatcher;

    public WpfDispatch(Dispatcher dispatcher) =>
        _dispatcher = dispatcher;

    public bool CheckAccess() => _dispatcher.CheckAccess();

    public void Invoke(Action action) => _dispatcher.Invoke(action);
}
```